# JQuery addClass not working with switch statement and is directive

Tags: jquery

addClass doesn't seem to work under certain circumstances for me. Have a look at the following code:

```
$("#my-div-container .my-sub-div li a").live('mouseover', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var li_parent_elem = $(this).parent();
    li_parent_elem.siblings().removeClass();

    switch(true)
    {
        case (li_parent_elem.is("#my-div-container .my-sub-div li:first-child") == true):
            //alert("First");
            li_parent_elem.addClass("first");
        break;

        case (li_parent_elem.is("#my-div-container .my-sub-div li:last-child") == true):
            //alert("Last");
            li_parent_elem.addClass("last");
        break;

        default:
            //alert("Mid");                     
            li_parent_elem.addClass("mid");
    }
});
```

addClass doesn't work for the first two case statements, only the default. However, when I uncomment the alert directives, I get the correct alert so I know the conditional statement is working.

I'm not sure what is wrong here, and I'd appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Can you post some html, maybe try setting up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can try and fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling I seem to have found a solution to this, even though I don't really like it because I don't understand why it works and the earlier code doesn't.

Here's the modified code:

```
$("#my-div-container .my-sub-div li a").live('mouseover', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var li_parent_elem = $(this).parent();
li_parent_elem.siblings().removeClass();

switch(true)
{
    case (li_parent_elem.is("#my-div-container .my-sub-div li:first-child") == true):
        //alert("First");
        li_parent_elem.removeAttr("class").addClass("first");
    break;

    case (li_parent_elem.is("#my-div-container .my-sub-div li:last-child") == true):
        //alert("Last");
        li_parent_elem.removeAttr("class").addClass("last");
    break;

    default:
        //alert("Mid");                     
        li_parent_elem.addClass("mid");
}
});
```

I'm still at a loss why even when I removed the switch statement and used if-else with my earlier code, it didn't work, but this does.

Maybe it's a bug or something.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need a switch there (and that switch looks quite broken!). Try this instead:

```
if (li_parent_elem.is("#my-div-container .my-sub-div li:first-child"))
    li_parent_elem.addClass("first");
else if (li_parent_elem.is("#my-div-container .my-sub-div li:last-child"))
    li_parent_elem.addClass("last");
else 
    li_parent_elem.addClass("mid");
```

Comment: Like I said, the switch conditional works, so this won't solve the problem. But just for good measure, I tried it and as expected it doesn't change anything. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Agree. I think you are over egging it with `== true):`. The purspose of the switch statement is that you are comparing a value to another value. It's a bit like saying "when it's the case that my value is = the value in the switch bit", then do something. ie you don't need to explicitly state the comparison at every case statement.

Comment: Ok. I'm not really concerned how it looks as long as it works, and using the alert test I previously alluded to, it works ok as a conditional statement. I just need to figure out why addClass() doesn't work inside the case even though alert() does.

Answer (score 1):

```
//More efficient event handler
$('#my-div-container .my-sub-div').delegate('li a', 'mouseover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var items = $(this).parent().siblings('li');

    //this could be chained to the line above
    items.removeClass();

    //no reason for a switch statement for something so simple
    //iterate over each element and check if its position
    items.each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':first')) {
            $(this).addClass('first');
        }
        else if($(this).is(':last')) {
            $(this).addClass('last');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('mid');
        }
    });
});
```

Improved:

```
$('#my-div-container .my-sub-div').delegate('li a', 'mouseover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var items = $(this).parent().siblings('li');

    items.removeClass().addClass(function() {
        return $(this).is(':first') ? 'first' : ($(this).is(':last') ? 'last' : 'mid');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this actually didn't work. Note that :first and :first-child are different, and :first-child is what I need based on the way my HTML is structured. Also, the iteration with each() is not what I need because I'm trying to addClass() to a single item on mouseover. The code you provided will addClass() to multiple siblings when I hover over a 'mid' item, which defeats the whole purpose of what I was trying to do.

Comment: Cool, I definitely misunderstood what you were looking for.  It's hard to figure that out ----> "I'm not really concerned how it looks as long as it works".  I'd try fixing that mantra and write more polished code so other coders can look at it and figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the snippets though, they've got me thinking about the delegate() function, which wasn't really in my vocabulary. Don't get me wrong, I like polished code, but I'd prefer to do that when the code works first and I understand what's going on before I make it more elegant, that's all I'm saying i.e. I'd like to make sure my if-else statement works before I look at making it a ternary operator to reduce line-size.